# Return of function(vector) remains empty from static class

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, return-value

I have several singleton classes. Two of them each run as a separate thread. In one class, two vectors are filled and that works. If I now call the getPlayersEnemy function in the other class, the vector is always empty and I don't know why.

Player-Class:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include "Structs.h"
#include <vector>

class Player
{
private:
    Player() {}

    std::vector<entity> playersTeam;
    std::vector<entity> playersEnemy;
    int local = 0;

public:
    static Player& getInstance()
    {
        static Player instance;
        return instance;
    }
    void obtainPlayers();
    std::vector<entity> getPlayersTeam();
    std::vector<entity> getPlayersEnemy();
};
```

The two get*-Functions:

```cpp
std::vector<entity> Player::getPlayersTeam()
{
    return playersTeam;
}

std::vector<entity> Player::getPlayersEnemy()
{
    return playersEnemy;
}
```

In the obtainPlayers function the vectors are getting filled(and also this is the function which runs in a thread)

Now, in the Categroize-Class, I init the Player class and call getPlayersTeam()/getPlayersEnemy():

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Categorize 
{
private:
    Categorize() {}
    Memory& mem = Memory::getInstance();
    Player& player = Player::getInstance();
    Game& game = Game::getInstance();
public:
    static Categorize & getInstance()
    {
        static Categorize instance;
        return instance;
    }
    void run();
};

void Categorize::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (game.isFullyLoaded())
        {
            if (player.getPlayersEnemy().empty())
            {
                std::cout << "empty vector" << std::endl;
            }

            for (const entity ent : player.getPlayersEnemy())
            {
                 std::cout << "called" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where they're getting filled:

```cpp
void Player::obtainPlayers()
{
    while (true)
    {
        playersTeam.clear();
        playersEnemy.clear();

        Entity& ent = Entity::getInstance();

        int localPlayer = ent.getLocalplayer();

        if (!localPlayer)
        {
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << ent.getHealth(localPlayer);

        playersTeam.push_back(
            entity
            {
                localPlayer,
                ent.getHealth(localPlayer),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                ent.getPosition(localPlayer)
            }
        );

        int localPlayerTeam = ent.getTeam(localPlayer);
        int team = 1;
        int enemy = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 64; i++)
        {
            int player = ent.getEntityByIndex(i);
            
            if (player == localPlayer || !player)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (ent.getTeam(player) == localPlayerTeam)
            {
                playersTeam.push_back(
                    entity{
                        player,
                        ent.getHealth(player),
                        ent.isDormant(player),
                        ent.isVisible(player, localPlayer),
                        ent.isSpotted(player),
                        ent.getPosition(player)
                    }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                playersEnemy.push_back(
                    entity{
                        player,
                        ent.getHealth(player),
                        ent.isDormant(player),
                        ent.isVisible(player, localPlayer),
                        ent.isSpotted(player),
                        ent.getPosition(player)
                    }
                );
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Also the Categorize::run() is also running in another thread.

I don't know why the return of getPlayersEnemy()/getPlayersTeam() is always empty, where it is not, when I check in the player-class itslef.

Comment: There is no function named `getPlayersFriendly` in the code shown. Also no evidence that `Player::playersTeam` member is ever populated; there is no reason to believe that it shouldn't be empty. For further assistance, show a [mcve].

Comment: @IgorTandetnik updated my question. getPlayersFriendly was a typo, I meaned getPlayersTeam or getPlayersEnemy, which exists.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `Player::obtainPlayers` and `Categorize::run` are running simultaneously in parallel on two threads. If so, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race, as you are reading an object in one thread while modifying the same object in another, with no synchronization.